Flutter android build requires a newer version of the Kotlin Gradle plugin
I am trying to build my flutter app using flutter 3.24.3. Earlier the app was successfully building with flutter version < 3. With flutter > 3, I am getting this error:
┌─ Flutter Fix ──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┐
│ [!] Your project requires a newer version of the Kotlin Gradle plugin.                                 │
│ Find the latest version on https://kotlinlang.org/docs/releases.html#release-details, then update the  │
│ version number of the plugin with id "org.jetbrains.kotlin.android" in the plugins block of            │
│ /home/ncd/AndroidStudioProjects/netr/android/settings.gradle.                                          │
│                                                                                                        │
│ Alternatively (if your project was created before Flutter 3.19), update                                │
│ /home/ncd/AndroidStudioProjects/netr/android/build.gradle                                              │
│ ext.kotlin_version = '<latest-version>'                                                                │
└────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┘

I have already updated the settings.gradle like so:
plugins {
    id "dev.flutter.flutter-plugin-loader" version "1.0.0"
    id "com.android.application" version "7.3.0" apply false
    id "org.jetbrains.kotlin.android" version "2.0.21" apply false
}

I searched for org.jetbrains.kotlin.android in the code:

grep -iIRn org.jetbrains.kotlin.android .
./android/settings.gradle:22:    id "org.jetbrains.kotlin.android" version "2.0.21" apply false
./windows/flutter/ephemeral/.plugin_symlinks/wakelock_plus/example/android/settings.gradle:22:    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android' version '1.8.22' apply false
./windows/flutter/ephemeral/.plugin_symlinks/package_info_plus/example/android/settings.gradle:22:    id "org.jetbrains.kotlin.android" version "1.9.23" apply false
./linux/flutter/ephemeral/.plugin_symlinks/wakelock_plus/example/android/settings.gradle:22:    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android' version '1.8.22' apply false
./linux/flutter/ephemeral/.plugin_symlinks/package_info_plus/example/android/settings.gradle:22:    id "org.jetbrains.kotlin.android" version "1.9.23" apply false

I feel the above shouldn't be cause of issue as the files are example.
And also search for ext.kotlin_version in the code:

grep -iIRn ext.kotlin_version .
./windows/flutter/ephemeral/.plugin_symlinks/wakelock_plus/android/build.gradle:5:    ext.kotlin_version = '1.7.22'
./windows/flutter/ephemeral/.plugin_symlinks/media_kit_video/example/android/build.gradle:2:    ext.kotlin_version = '1.7.10'
./windows/flutter/ephemeral/.plugin_symlinks/package_info_plus/android/build.gradle:5:    ext.kotlin_version = '1.7.22'
./linux/flutter/ephemeral/.plugin_symlinks/wakelock_plus/android/build.gradle:5:    ext.kotlin_version = '1.7.22'
./linux/flutter/ephemeral/.plugin_symlinks/media_kit_video/example/android/build.gradle:2:    ext.kotlin_version = '1.7.10'
./linux/flutter/ephemeral/.plugin_symlinks/package_info_plus/android/build.gradle:5:    ext.kotlin_version = '1.7.22'

However, I am not sure if the above is causing the issue as these files exist in linux and windows directories, while the android build is failing.
Can someone please help me understand how to fix this issue?
I am building using the command flutter build apk. And expected the build to be a success. Also note the linux build of the above app succeeds.

i get this proble and solve it with this code added to app/build.gradle
    allprojects {
               .
               .
               .       
          } // keep all project and under it add this code
    ext {
        compileSdkVersion   = 34
        targetSdkVersion    = 34
        appCompatVersion    = "1.7.0" }

and under the :
rootProject.buildDir = '../build'

add this lines of code :
subprojects {
    afterEvaluate {
        android {
            compileSdkVersion 34
        }
    }
}

then run again
flutter build apk

